# Issues while testing android app with real phone

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to test my code using real phone device, not with emulator (problem with HAX). But my app is keep getting crashed.I checked the logcat and not able to determine the exact problem.

Please find the log here:
[Logcat of android studio](http://pastebin.com/k6KLqS4K)

**MainActivity.Java :**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void convert(View view)
    {
        EditText DollarField= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.DollarField);
        Double DollarValue = Double.parseDouble(DollarField.getText().toString());

        Double rupeesValue = DollarValue* 67.58;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Rs"+rupeesValue.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.tricksfind.www.currencyconverter"
    >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Design:**

[image]

Please suggest.

Comment: Please show your crash log.

Comment: pls show your manifest

Comment: Can you paste only the part (from the log file) where your app crashed ? It would be easier to understand

Comment: Don't you have `onCreate()` method in your `MainActivity` ?

Comment: Please don't use PasteBin. You can directly copy paste your logcat into your question

Comment: Either you intentionally left the `onCreate()` method or you have not included in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you don't have `onCreate()` method overridden from `AppCompatActivity`

So, you have to `Override` and do the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`. You cannot find the view untill you set it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // replace with your layout file name
    }

    public void convert(View view)
    {
        EditText DollarField= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.DollarField);
        Double DollarValue = Double.parseDouble(DollarField.getText().toString());

        Double rupeesValue = DollarValue* 67.58;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Rs"+rupeesValue.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed again super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: @Praveenks As pointed again, you are missing the line: `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in `onCreate(...)`